# Accept and Cancel buttons are disabled in Google "Request for Permission" window

Tags: google-account, permissions, feedly

When I try to log in to Feedly on a specific computer using my Google account, the normal "Request for Permission" window opens, but the buttons are disabled. What can be the reason and is there any workaround? I can log into StackExchange from the same Google account on the same computer.

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled?

Comment: Yes. However, when I open the Developer Tools console, it shows "failed to load resource" messages for https://ssl.gstatic.com, and trying to open these files in the browser leads to errors about untrusted certificates, which looks promising.

Comment: Are there different plugins installed on this other machine/browser? Presumably another browser is OK?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the proxy.